# Two maps to compare key and update value with splitting the key data

Tags: java, hashmap

First Code:
I have two Maps

```
Map<String, String> mapA; //key: /content/common/pqr and value: /apps/content/data/abc
Map<String, String> mapB; //key: /parsys/content/banner/pqr and value: /apps/comment/data
```

In the above two map MapA has key **/content/common/pqr** if this matches key of MapB **/parsys/content/banner/pqr**, for matching we need to split and check the leaf of the key i.e pqr and leave the rest then **MapB value** should be updated with **MapA value**

We have around 1000+ Key value pair. There will not be multiple entries ending with pqr.

I have to update MapB comparing the keys.

Comment: Not a JNI question, and a very unclear Java question at that.

Comment: @Botje check now

Comment: Ronnie, I think your question is a bit unclear: you say that mapA has key /pqr but that is only part of the key? what is the rule to match between keys in both maps? Also what is the size of the maps?

Comment: `if(keyA.split("/")[2].equals(keyA.split("/")[3])){
    mapB.put(keyB, mapA.get(keyA));}`

Comment: @OrenYosifon We have rule that /pqr should be there. In other words their leaf node should be similar. Size of map would be around 1000 keys  or maybe more.

Comment: @c0der [0][1][2] is visible here but in the problem that I am solving it consist of long texts as well.

MapA-key: /content/consumer/en_us/productions/product
Map-B-Key: /b2c/north_america/websites/en_us/product/parsys/ecom/product

Comment: What if multiple keys in mapA end with `pqr` but have  different values, with which value do you want to replace the occurrences in mapB? First, last, random ...?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all essential information to it. Not in comments. Show what you tried and tell us where you have a problem (ask a question. There is no question in the post)

Answer (score 0):

For each entry in `mapA` iterate over the key set of `mapB` checking if a key exists which ends with the same substring using `String#substring` and `String#lastIndexOf`. If such a key is present remapp with value from `mapA` using `Map#compute`

```
mapA.forEach((k, v) -> {
        Optional<String> key = mapB.keySet().stream()
                .filter(s -> s.endsWith(k.substring(k.lastIndexOf('/'))))
                .findFirst();
        if (key.isPresent()){
            mapB.compute(key.get(), (a, b) -> v);
        }            
    });
```

Comment: Seems perfect IMHO